# How can I set one of HKEY_USERS as HKEY_CURRENT_USER for several desktop apps?

Tags: c#, .net, format, registry, region

I have C#/.NET big project that also uses additional functionality of another program. These programs needs to be in en-US region, but not everyone customer has this region. I can change some settings in registry for projects correct working, but It will affect for all windows system (I need to change decimal separator, data formats and many other setting that have to be from en-US region format). My idea was to set new registry key that I somehow will be able to use in only my projects, whereas all system will use current user registry key.

My goals:

1. set **en-US** region format for only several programs (to the second program I don't have access, It bring parameters [like decimal separator] from HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry).
2. do not affect on the system region and HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry settings.

[image]

Comment: If you want a program, that reads from current_user, to read from John's registry data, you run the program as John

Comment: Is this a desktop app (console, WinForms, WPF, etc.) or something else.  Admins can write to any of the users under HKEY_USERS, but non-admins only have access to HKCU.  I'm curious why _These programs needs to be in en-US region_?  That seems like an odd specification.

Comment: I need to use special region format on the system level and only for several programs. I don't know how to cope with it. I can create this 'John' for program purpose and for program lifetime. Maybe there are other ways to determine special region for a concrete program?

Comment: Okey, these programs don't need to be exactly in en-US region. They need to use '.' as decimal separator, special data formats, sList like ',' and so on. I don't know why It is not working with comma as decimal separator for example. Our data is stored only with point decimal separator, so in c# I can use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture. However, in the other programs that we use, I cannot edit code.